# web service for "fake" cross domain requests?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

does there exist a service that will let me fetch the contents of another page and return it in some ways i can console via javascript?

i need to make a cross domain request, and i am trying to find a way to do so without writing my own web service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) in newer browsers if the server is set up to do it. You have [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) if the server you are making the request too supports it.

You can use [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) and let it generate the JSON for you to make the request with JSONP.

You can just turn off your browser's security and let the Ajax calls flow in. >:)

Or you can bite the bullet and write a few lines of serverside code for your proxy which probably would have taken the same amount of time to write as it took me to write this response.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with epascarello. Just whip up some a `cURL` class specific to the site you want to hit. I'd guess 20 lines, tops, including sanitizing a few parameters.